# How can I do a Propensity Score Matching with Instrumental Variables in R?

Tags: r, matching

I'm trying to do a PSM with IV. I've  read [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2677744.pdf) and I would like to apply it to my script (in R). I've done a PSM with my data, one example is following:

```
d=data 
 X=vars #List of covariables
 Y=y
 Tr=x 
 glm1=glm(psf,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=d) #PSM 
 XATT=Match(Y=y,Tr=x,X=glm1$fitted,M=1,estimand="ATT", 
 ties=FALSE,version="fast")
 summary(XATT)
```

Now, I'm interested in doing the previous process with an IV called 'z'. Ichimura & Taber (2001) suggest two propensity-score methods that use instrumental variables, but I do not know if there are other ways to do a PSM-IV in R, so in case of some of you know a different way to achieve it, I'd deeply appreciate it.

Any help I'll extremely grateful.

Comment: I'd suggest the `MatchIt` package. Reading the package's [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/matchit.pdf), seemed very straightforward to me, though there're some issues with the [optimal](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/18) and [genetic matching](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/19) methods.

Comment: Thanks @jaySf   , I'll look at your references.

Comment: @jaySF Could you point me to the part that discusses instrumental variable matching in the vignette?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov For my understanding you do matching first and analyse IVs after, see also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163652/instrumental-variable-analysis-after-propensity-matching), accordingly an R matching package should be helpful. Anyway, I also want to point at the `Matching` and the `optmatch` packages; in the former a help file for `?GenMatch` can be found and both in summary solve the issues I mentioned. (For a brief overview of Matching methods see Morgan & Winship 2015. _Counterfactuals and Causal Inference._ Chap. 5.4.1 f.)